# Display alert even if disabled in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to show the alert window in chrome even if the user has checked the checkbox that says 'Prevent this page from creating additional dialog' on the previous alert.
I tried different things but none of them seems to work after user selected to prevent the alerts.
I read somewhere that if the time difference between two alerts is 1000ms or more, chrome never shows the checkbox to prevent alert. But, it doesn't seem to work.
I did something like this:

```
var count = 1;
function showAlert(){
    if(count <= 50){
        alert("Alert Window : " + count);
        count++;

        setTimeout(function(){
            showAlert();
        }, 1000);
    }
}

setTimeout(function(){
    showAlert();
}, 1000);
```

When I run this code on my machine it never shows the checkbox to prevent the further alerts even when I reduce the time to 100ms. On other's machine it shows the checkbox to prevent alerts after two alerts. Both have the same version of chrome.
So, is it possible to display alert even if the user chose not to see or I have to go for some workaround to never show the disable checkbox to the user.
Thanks.

Comment: Haha :D If the user don't want your spam, just accept that

Comment: I don't think this is possible you may wan't to try an own alert made with html and css

Comment: I think this impossible, what you can try to do is implement your own "alert" using javascript and css.

Comment: This is not possible by design. Trying to work around it is only possible using a custom dialog (with HTML/CSS). Be aware that there's a reason behind why this behaviour exists.

Comment: Is it true that if the time difference between two alerts >=1000ms, chrome doesn't show the prevent checkbox?